# Create a list of arrays

Tags: c#

My code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1CS
{
    class Program
    {
        private static List<string[]> list;
        //private static string input;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            list = new List<string[]>();

            int n = 2;

            //------PROBLEM IS HERE::
            string[,] Ar = new string[n,3];
            Ar[0,0] = "A";
            Ar[0,1] = "133";
            Ar[0,2] = "2";
            list.Add(Ar[0]);

            Ar[1,0] = "d";
            Ar[1,1] = "4";
            Ar[1,2] = "2";
            list.Add(Ar);
            //---------------------

            //sort
            var sum = from s in list orderby (Int32.Parse(s[1]) + Int32.Parse(s[2])) select s;
            //change for array
            Array sumn = sum.ToArray();

            foreach (String[] s in sumn)
            {
                String result = String.Join(" ", s);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a list of string arrays. As you can see in each row of array Ar there is:

```
0 column is name of point
1 column is x coordinate
2 column is y coordinate
```

I want to sort points in ascending order with respect to their sum of coordinates. Is there an option to use list of arrays to solve this problem(yes/no and why)? If there isn't pls give me another solution.

Comment: @Fredou Why does it matter whether it is or not?

Comment: @Servy, depending if it is or not, i would explain how instead of solving

Comment: @Fredou Why would you not explain the solution regardless?  You think that anyone not solving a homework problem doesn't need to understand the solution to their problem?

Comment: @Servy, i used the wrong way to explain myself, sorry, i would do both if it wasn't a homework and only explain if it was a homework.

Comment: No. It's only training. I've done this exercise in C++ but now I'm learning C# and I just want to solve this exercise by different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List<string[]>`

```
List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();
string[] ar = new string[3];
ar[0] = "A";
ar[1] = "133";
ar[2] = "2";
rows.Add(ar);

/* 
   be advised that you can't just go further without creating a new array, 
   as you did in your code 
*/
ar = new string[3];
ar[0] = "D";
ar[1] = "4";
ar[2] = "2";
rows.Add(ar);
```

... altough I would heavily suggest using structures instead, as they're cleaner, faster and easier to use.

Using `struct`, it would look like this:

```
struct Row {
    string name;
    int x;
    int y;
}

List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
Row r = new Row();
r.name = "A";
r.x = 133;
r.y = 2;
rows.Add(r);

r = new Row();
r.name = "B";
r.x = 4;
r.y = 2;
rows.Add(r);
```

Comment: This isn't really any better than what the OP is currently doing.  He most certainly should not be using a two-dimensional structure here, whether it be jagged (as you're doing with a list of arrays) or through an actual multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Just hold it till I have a chance to extend the last sentence in my post. Yah, I did recommend using structures, yet you disagreed.

Comment: If your answer isn't yet ready to be evaluated, then you shouldn't have posted it yet.

Comment: Mutable structs should be avoided at all costs, and as this type is not logically representing a single value, it shouldn't be a `struct` at all.

Comment: why a struct is better? why not a class?

Comment: @Fredou, no one said structs are better.

Comment: @user35443 What makes you say that?  You're the one that posted an answer that you felt was incomplete.

Comment: sry but shouldnt you use  public string name;
            public int x;
            public int y; in Row struct?

Comment: @Servy I did, as you can see in the edit history, point out that the whole thing could be done through structures, and you were the one who didn't apparently read the post to the end. But that's not important anymore, let's forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a two dimensional array in which one of the dimensions is used to determine which value of a single logical object is used, you should instead create a new `class`.  Give that class three properties, and create a single dimensional data structure (whether it be an array or a list) of objects of that new custom type.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you should avoid using a array of string since you could have 1 issue. what if some some reason index 1 and 2 of the array are not parsable to int?

also using a class would explain exactly what are the value, also see what Servy said.

you asked for another solution so here is one that seem to work with the information that you gave.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Coord>();
            list.Add(new Coord() { Name = "a", X = 133, Y = 2 });
            list.Add(new Coord() { Name = "d", X = 4, Y = 2 });

            var sum = list.OrderBy(x => x.X + x.Y);

            foreach(var s in sum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.ToString(" "));
            }

            Console.Read();

        }
    }

    class Coord
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public string ToString(string sep = "")
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{3}{1}{3}{2}", Name, X, Y, sep);
        }
    }
}
```